# Feed randomly gone on SE Android app

Tags: bug, android-app, android-app-feed

SE Android App Version: 1.0.84

There is a display issue in the Feed section. The *Earlier today*, the below sections and the post title are not visible.

There is no exact steps to reproduce. It doesn't happen when the app is initializing. But if you open the Stack Exchange app, navigate to some other apps, then come back after few minutes, I can see this issue (but not all the time).

When the issue is there, if I manually click the *Feed* option in the navigation sidebar, the display issue is fixed.

I have recorded the issue:

[image: Display issue in Feed section]