# Hot Network Question's title is hidden by a bar on Android's app feed

Tags: bug, android-app, android-app-feed

The heading/category of the topic above the question is not visible. It is overlapped by the bar.

> [image: title is hidden]

- App Version: 1.0.85
- Device Manufacturer: samsung
- Device Model: i9500
- OS Version: 5.1.1 (N920CXXU1AOH2)

Comment: After consideration, actually [Feed randomly gone on Android app](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277841/feed-randomly-gone-on-se-android-app) should be the correct dupe target.